# Allowing certains keys through a numeric textbox's keypress, keyup event

Tags: javascript, textbox, asp.net-ajax, dom-events, keypress

Here's my code and it uses asp.net ajax client library to add event handlers

```
function IsDigit(id) { //short variable,args name for best minification
    if ($get(id)) {
        var v = function (e) {
                var r = /\d/;
                if (!r.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) e.preventDefault();
            }
        $addHandlers($get(id), {
            keydown: v
        });
    }
}
```

`$get(ID)` gets the control with the id
`$addHandlers` adds event **Handlers** to the control. Here i attach it to the control with ID `id`. It all works well the textbox accepts only numeric input, but the problem is when he wants to delete all numeric and wants to enter some other numbers. So something like <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>HOME</kbd> and then delete, <kbd>Delete</kbd> are not working. Please can someone refine the code better. Also is Keydown optimal for this kind of job
I temporarily solved it by doing this, but this does allow unexpected characters for brief second then removes it

```
function IsDigit(id) { //short variable,args name for best minification
    if ($get(id)) {
        var p = "";
        var v = function (e) {
                var r = /^\d*$/;
                if (r.test(this.value)){p = this.value;} else {this.value=p;}// e.preventDefault();
            }
        $addHandlers($get(id), {
            keyup: v
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just clarify what the input field is allowed to contain please? Should it only contain numeric data?

Comment: @Ian Oxley yes only numeric data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to do your validation `onkeydown` / `onkeyup` you might find it easier to validate `onblur`. That way you don't have to worry about the various key combinations that someone might use to select / delete / re-type text e.g. ctrl + arrow keys, ctrl + v for pasting text, ctrl + a to select all.

You could always use the new HTML5 `<input type="number">` to constrain the input, then use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to add your event handler code for browsers that don't support the new input type:

```
if (Modernizr.inputtypes.number) {
    ...
    // Add your code in here
    ...
}
```

Comment: adding 50K for extra 3 lines is an bandwidth hogger, +more useless code